# Finding custom includes directories with autoconf

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, include-path, festival

I'm trying to compile a program which uses the festival library.

Basically, the requirements are that you include the festival *and* estools header directories in the include path, and you include both their library paths.

In a normal installation, they simply stay in their own folders, so you have

```
/some/path/festival/src/include 
/some/other/path/estools/include
```

as the required search path, and

```
/some/path/festival/src/lib
/some/other/path/estools/lib
```

as the library path.

I think that the proper way to handle this is with a "--with-estools" and a  "--with-festival" configure option.

However, there's a different setup when it is installed on a debian/ubuntu system.
I'd like to be able to handle this setup, where the search paths are

```
/usr/include/festival
/usr/include/estools
```

and the search path is just

```
/usr/lib
```

I'd like to detect the second case, and handle it automatically, while still requiring the user to specify the first two directories if the second case is not satisfied.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something that would preclude setting options like so?

1. --festival-includes with a default value (if unset) to /usr/include/festival
2. --festival-libs with a default value (if unset) to /usr/lib/libfestival.XXX

The same goes for estools.

Comment: This requires twice as many command line options as I would like.  Also, I'd really like to detect any file in SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY/festival/festival.h and be smart enough to just add SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY/festival to the search path.

Comment: Okay,thanks.  I was confused about autotools.  This is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the package maintainer to worry about these details at all; it is the responsibility of the user.  If the user has installed a library in a non-standard location, then the user needs to add LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib to a CONFIG_SITE file or to every invocation of configure or put that path in the compiler's search path through some system dependent mechanism.  Similarly, the user should append -I/path/to/include to CPPFLAGS.

In other words, debian is doing the right thing by simply installing the libraries and headers in the standard location.  Anyone choosing to install the libraries in a non-standard location is giving themselves more work.  It's not your responsibility to fix their mistakes.

Adding options like --with-festival or --with-festival-headers is not helpful; the user can just as easily assign to LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS, and those variables are standardized.

Comment: +1 for not reimplementing the wheel with the wrong tools.  An option like ``--with-festival`` is legitimate when ``--without-festival`` means something.  In other words, ``--with``/``--without`` options are meant to enable *or disable* the use of some other package.  The actual configuration of search paths occurs with ``LDFLAGS`` and ``CPPFLAGS``.

Answer (score 1):

Some platforms have adopted the Filesystem Heirarchy Standard - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard .

This should really be reflected in autoconf, instead of insisting that the user should deal with it by setting CFLAGS, because /opt/openssl/lib is no longer a "non-standard" location.

The FHS also specifies that /usr/local is a "Tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host." So arguably, /opt should really be checked first.

More on FHS /opt -> http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES